# Segmented control vs toggle switch

Tags: gui-design, filter, tabs, controls, toggle

We have a dashboard that allows a user to see all jobs belonging to their firm. These jobs are split into two tabs:

1. Upcoming jobs
2. Requested jobs (but haven't been yet been confirmed by us. Once it's been confirmed, these jobs transfer to the first tab)

Within each tab, while it's helpful to see all jobs within the firm, our users would like to be able to filter and see only jobs that were booked by them.

Would a segmented control be better or a toggle switch?

**Segmented control approach:**

[image]

**Toggle switch approach:**

- This could also just be a simple checkbox
- My only hesitation about the toggle is that it appears more like a setting than a filter, so might end up using a checkbox instead. However, with that said, this is technically a setting since we would like to persist it as some users may only really want to see their own jobs

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Carbon Design System](https://carbondesignsystem.com/components/content-switcher/usage/#when-not-to-use) lists this logic for choosing between Toggles and Content Switchers:

> For binary actions or choices, such as “yes/no” or “on/off” use a toggle instead of a content switcher. A content switcher can be used for binary views, like switching between a grid and list view but should not be used as a binary input control.

Seems like in your case both could work, however Content Switcher has a number of advantages over Toggles:

- **Expandability**. Imagine in the future you'll have more options for filtering the list, not just those two - if you use Content Switcher now, all you'll have to in the future is add new options to it. If you use Toggle, you'll have to redesign the whole selection which will affect the users that are used to the old way.
- **Ambiguity**. Sometimes Toggles can be ambiguous - Content Switchers have labels, so it's less likely people won't understand which option is chosen and what will happen when they switch it. If designed properly, of course.
- **Accessibility**: With proper labeling and design, content switchers can be more accessible for screen reader users, as the options are more descriptive.

I'd go with ContentSwitcher in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Another thing that's throwing me off is - if you look at the tabs on the left, they're also technically ContentSwtichers. So both tabs and ContentSwtichers are somewhat functionally the same, just visually different.